# SQLAlchemy how to insert base64 string in a column

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, base64

I've a problem when try to insert a base64 string in the database of the server. The data is received correctly from the client.

This is the table:

```
from app import db

class Example(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'example'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    image = db.Column(db.LargeBinary)
    description = db.Column(db.String(120))
```

And when I receive the data I try to insert by this way.

```
example.image = request.json['image']
```

But launch this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (builtins.TypeError) memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' [SQL: 'INSERT INTO example (image, description) VALUES (?, ?)'] [parameters: [{'image':''iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAASwAAACWCAYAAABkW7XSAAAgAElEQVR4Xkyd65Ikx5GdI+9ZWVXdMwOQMtPF9EM/dDEtd0GQS4LgLk2m938KmWklApjprlveM/V9XsM1cUURmOmuyozwcD9+/LhH9 ... (131066 characters truncated) ... U+bq1fYzK8CjL+Htr9jmjGZaL/sAccUiPf8/8906GpLwkQngOCuh5nohrdndHTRHii8Q55Rlk2N1B1ZGCCmSIct5gm/IiAAAAEklEQVSsvzbg3YTp3ut72d+/AvI8T5jSrxmzAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC'','description':'Example description'}]]
```

Any solution for this?

Comment: Don't save files in a database.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/38829952/267540

Comment: @e4c5 Thanks, It's a good option

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong `Column` type here. Because Base64 is actually `ASCII` encoded variable length string, you should use `TEXT` instead of `LargeBinary`. This should solve your problem. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Not storing files in a database avoids this issue. However, to answer the question: I think is that 
request.json['image'] returns a str that needs to be encoded to bytes first like so:

```
request.json['image'].encode('utf-8')
```

given the encoding is of course 'utf-8'